# How to get a type that is twice the size as the specified type in a templated function?

Tags: c++

I have a function that does some math with varying precision, the provided type can be either uint8_t, uint16_t or uint32_t

While inside the function though, there is a multiplication that can have a result larger than the input type can hold so for example in case the input is in uint32_t, that multiplication needs to be done using uint64_t.

For now I could just use a 64b integer for all of them but right after that I'm also going to make an SSE version of the function so I'd like to keep the type as small as possible for the practice run too.

Since the function is very long, I'll just use a short example of the same problem:

```
template <typename T>
uint32_t multiply_and_return_lower_value(T a, T b) {
    auto big_result = static_cast<Magic>(a) * b;
    return static_cast<T>(big_result);
}
```

So in place of the "Magic" I need to get the type that is twice as big as T.

I figured this could possibly done in a similar fasion to std::numeric_limits so something like

```
auto big_result = static_cast<my_func_that_somehow_returns_a_type<T>::get_type()>(a) * b;
```

But I've no idea what to even google since a function can't actually return a type and while I vaguely remember somehow storing and using a type before, I don't remember any of the keywords involved.

Comment: `T[2]` is exactly twice as large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "function that returns a type" (given another type) is, well, a class template (or a *typedef-name* defined in one); they are often called "traits classes" when used this way.  There probably isn't anything lying around specifically for "double this size", but it's not hard to make your own:

```
template<class> struct width2;  // undefined
template<> struct width2<uint8_t> {
  using type=uint16_t;
};
// more explicit specializations...
template<class T> using width2_t=typename width2<T>::type; // for convenience

// Usage:
auto big_result = static_cast<width2_t<T>>(a) * b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just implement a mapping using a specialized template.

```
template<typename int_t> struct int_squared;

template<>
struct int_squared<uint8_t> {

   typedef uint16_t type;
};

template<typename T>
using int_squared_t=typename int_squared<T>::type;
```

With that, `int_squared_t<T>` in a template, with the template parameter `T` being a `uint8_t` results in `uint16_t`, here.

Add the obvious specializations for `uint16_t` and `uint32_t`, and you're done.